# libjasper1 depends on inexistant libjpeg8

Tags: debian, apt, libraries

I'm trying to run a binary, but I'm missing a library : `libjasper.so.1`

This is an Qt app, and is neither complex or heavy.
I'm running this on Debian 12, KDE Plasma 5.

When trying to install the package `libjasper-dev`, it looks for `libjpeg8 (>= 8c)` *but it is not installable*.
I've seen that the package is now called `libjpeg-turbo8`, which I successfully installed, but the dependency is still broken.

In my research, I had to add a lot of new apt repository URL if you're wondering.

Does anyone know what I could do in order to have a running app ?